# Why does Category dtype not handle != NaN comparisons correctly?

Tags: python, pandas

There seems to be inconsistent behavior in the `!=` comparison depending upon whether the item belongs to the categories. If the value is in the categories `!= NaN` returns False, seemingly inconsistent with how the normal `!= NaN` comparison would evaluate. When the value is not in the categories, the behavior seems expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Standard evaluation
'11' != np.NaN
#True

'A' != np.NaN
#True

s = pd.Series([np.NaN, '11']).astype('category')

s.ne('11')
#0    False   # <- What?
#1    False
#dtype: bool

s.ne('A')
#0    True
#1    True
#dtype: bool

# Without the category type the behavior is correct
pd.Series([np.NaN, '11']).ne('11')
#0     True
#1    False
#dtype: bool
```

Is this a bug, or for some reason the expected `NaN` behavior within categories? `pd.__version__ = 0.25.0`, but also appears on `1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems the way `NaN`s are treated when working with *category* type data. With Categorical data, values that are not included in *categories* are replaced by `NaN`, i.e a `NaN` is treated just as a non existent category. We can check by creating a series as the following and specifying the existent categories:

```
c = pd.Categorical(values=['1','2',np.nan,'3','4'], categories=['1','2','3'])

print(c)
[1, 2, NaN, 3, NaN]
Categories (3, object): [1, 2, 3]
```

And by checking the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) we see that:

> Missing values should not be included in the Categorical’s categories, only in the values. Instead, it is understood that NaN is different, and is **always a possibility**

So missing values are being considered to always be a possibility when compared to a value from an existent category.

Using the above example we can see the same behavior with a missing value `NaN` and a value of a non existent category `'4'`:

```
c != '3'
array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

Comment: I know I have been playing with it and I'm quite puzzled with this too. Perhaps explicit equality comparison does not show this behavior for some reason? I'm not sure...-

Comment: No I think I see what you're saying. This has been helpful. I think I will probably stop working with categorical because this greatly complicates some of my comparisons. :D

Comment: Well this is as much as I could find digging a little, hope it helped :) @ALollz