# Trouble casting NaNs to type 'category' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I'm having trouble with nan values after converting them with `astype('category')`. I am using pandas 1.1.3 and numpy 1.19.1.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

employees = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'First Name':['Douglas', 'Thomas', 'Maria'],
                                'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female'],
                                'Start Date': ['1993-08-06', '1996-03-31', np.datetime64('NaT')],
                                'Salary':[0, 61933, 130590],
                                'Mgmt': [True, True, False],
                                'Team': ['Marketing', np.nan, 'Finance']})
```

Before conversion when you test the individual elements of a slice of elements the result is the same.

```py
>>> employees.loc[1, 'Team'] != 'Finance'
True

>>> employees['Team'] != 'Finance'
True  
True  
False
```

However after casting to `astype('category')` the result of the logic test is different between the individual elements and the slice:

```
>>> employees['Team'] = employees['Team'].astype('category')
>>> employees.loc[1, 'Team'] != 'Finance'
True

>>> employees['Team'] != 'Finance'
True  
False  
False
```

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: What are your pandas and numpy versions? Both before and after the conversion the results are the same for me (True, True, False).

Comment: I had a similar question years with older versions, ago. Still not sure I understand why this happened, but seems to have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60511951/why-does-category-dtype-not-handle-nan-comparisons-correctly

Comment: With pandas 1.3.4 (and numpy 1.21.4), I'm **not** able to reproduce this. Copying the code straight from the post, the output for both is T, T, F.

Comment: Upgrading to pandas 1.3.4 and numpy 1.21.1 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#missing-data) say that `nan` is not a valid category entry -

> Missing values should not be included in the Categorical’s categories,
> only in the values. Instead, it is understood that NaN is different,
> and is always a possibility. When working with the Categorical’s
> codes, missing values will always have a code of -1

The `nan` in your dataframe will compare not equal to any valid categorical entry, i.e.

```
(df['Team_Cat'] != 'Finance')[1] == (df['Team_Cat'] == 'Finance')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful but not sure it is the full answer, after upgrading to pandas 1.3.4 and numpy 1.21.1 the issue has gone away